# Run Program (Alt+F2) can't type-ahead anymore? (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying Alt+f2 but I need to type and navigate folders.  It seems necessary to type out entries paths to get to where I'm going.  The best match folder appears but  clicking on it closes the run window and pollutes the history and does nothing.  That does not seem right..  Additionally, the matching folder has a ...in the name chopping off so it can not be seen.

So, I go to use the file manager to grab the path but the path is now buttons and the shortcut to show a path seems to be changing.